# Taking CSV Field and Extracting Links to Separate Python-DocX Paragraphs

Tags: python, csv, python-docx

I'm working on a Python project that takes as CSV output file and re-formats the data and puts it into a Word Document using Python-DocX. Everything so far works great, but working with multiple hyperlinks in the same field causes all links to point to just the first link of the set.

Currently this is the code that is causing the issue:

```
        p7 = document.add_paragraph()
        hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p7, row['See Also'], str(row['See Also']))
```

As you can see the blank paragraph is initialised and then the hyperlink is assigned to it. row['See Also'] is the row that contains the links I need to work with. Some entries contain a single link and some contain a lot.

This (https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74) is the function that adds the hyperlink as per the documented method for Python-Docx:

```
def add_hyperlink(paragraph, url, text):
    # This gets access to the document.xml.rels file and gets a new relation id value
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(
        url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK,
        is_external=True
    )

    # Create the w:hyperlink tag and add needed values
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )

    # Create a w:r element
    new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r')

    # Create a new w:rPr element
    rPr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:rPr')

    # Join all the xml elements together add add the required text to the w:r element
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = text
    hyperlink.append(new_run)

    paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)

    return hyperlink
```

The way I thought to do it was to use a for loop to iterate through each hyperlink in the field and assign them to a paragraph each, that way the hyperlinks should work just fine. I tried the following but this just creates 1000's of links which do not work right.

```
for x in row['See Also']:
    p = document.add_paragraph()
    hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, row['See Also'], row['See Also'])
```

I'm currently testing with a very small CSV file with just two sets of data as follows:

```
https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2016/08/24/sweet32/
```

This of course causes no issue and the hyperlink works as expected, however the following causes all links to point to the first address.

```
https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/security/ASA-2006-217.htm
http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/JARL-5ZQR4D
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IY55949
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IY55950
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IY62006
http://www.juniper.net/support/security/alerts/niscc-236929.txt
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms05-019
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms06-064
http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/JARL-5YGQ9G
http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/JARL-5ZQR7H
http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/JARL-5YGQAJ
http://www.nessus.org/u?cf64c2ca
https://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?date=2004-04-20
```

The fix is probably quite straight forward, any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough of the context code to show the specifics, but I suspect your problem is in the line:

```
for x in row['See Also']:
```

If you run:

```
for x in row['See Also']:
    print x
```

I think you'll get:

```
h
t
t
p
s
:
...
```

As you can see, using a string value as the iterable in a for loop iterates the characters of the string.

What I think you need instead is something like:

```
for row in csv_rows:
    p = document.add_paragraph()
    hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, row['See Also'], row['See Also'])
```

Comment: What you suggested is the same method I am currently using, currently I use that to post a number of rows from the CSV file it takes as input. The issue seems to be that because the See Also row is multi-lined in some cases, that it's applying the first item as the hyperlink for all the subsequent links in the list.

Comment: I have fixed the issue now, with the following code:

for row in csv_rows:
      links = row['See Also'].split("\n")
      for item in links:
       p = document.add_paragraph()
       hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, item, item)

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue out and the following code solves the problem:

```
for row in csv_rows:
        links = row['See Also'].split("\n")
        for item in links:
            p = document.add_paragraph()
            hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, item, item)
```

This splits each line of the 'See Also' row into a list and then this list is iterated through with each item being turned into a hyperlink.